How to remove the ground plane in a mesh using pymeshlab
I used COLMAP to compute the 3D reconstruction of some objects based on images. I use COLMAP to compute the poisson mesh reconstruction. Nonetheless, the .ply file created by COLMAP comes with the ground plane. An example can be seen on the image bellow, the reconstructed cube have a ground under it. I need to remove only this ground. Can someone give the path to solve the problem?

I do not try anything yet. I don't know how to start to solve the problem. I'm expecting if not a python script the solves the problem what's the way to solve it.
